# Getting error when I execute cypher query using neo4jclient and c# ,net core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, neo4j, neo4jclient

I can run this query successfully in the neo4j browser and I get this result

Query:
MATCH (user:User {name: 'bob'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Group)-[:INHERITS_PERMISSIONS_FROM*0..]->(parent_group:Group)
WITH ( parent_group.permissions)+( group.permissions) as permissions
unwind permissions as permissionslist
RETURN COLLECT( DISTINCT permissionslist)

Result:
["MarketingResearch", "MarketingRead"]

How do I execute this using c#, .net core 6, Neo4jClient

If I try executing it using the Neo4jClient I get the error below:

```
var testquery = "(user:User {name: 'bob'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Group)-[:INHERITS_PERMISSIONS_FROM*0..]->(parent_group:Group) WITH ( parent_group.permissions)+( group.permissions) as permissions unwind permissions as permissionslist RETURN COLLECT( DISTINCT permissionslist) as userpermissions";

var resultset = graphClient.Cypher
                .Match(testquery)
                .Return((userpermissions) => new 
                {
                    permissions=userpermissions.As<List<string>>()
                }).ResultsAsync.Result;
```

Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AggregateException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'One or more errors occurred.'
Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
Innermost exception     Neo4jClient.NeoException : Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: RETURN can only be used at the end of the query (line 1, column 223 (offset: 222))
"MATCH (user:User {name: 'bob'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Group)-[:INHERITS_PERMISSIONS_FROM*0..]->(parent_group:Group) WITH ( parent_group.permissions)+( group.permissions) as permissions unwind permissions as permissionslist RETURN COLLECT( DISTINCT permissionslist) as userpermissions"

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives the reason, `RETURN can only be used at the end of the query`, what you are doing is using two `RETURN` statements, one in your `testquery` and the other in your fluent query when you do `.Return`.

If you want to execute a string, then I would recommend using the official driver (Neo4j.Driver) - but to use the Neo4jClient for your query - you'd need to write it like this:

```cs
var query = graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User {name: 'bob'})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Group)-[:INHERITS_PERMISSIONS_FROM*0..]->(parent_group:Group)")
    .With("(parent_group.permissions)+( group.permissions) AS permissions")
    .Unwind("permissions", "permissionslist")
    .Return((permissionslist) => permissionslist.CollectAsDistinct<string>());

var results = await query.ResultsAsync;
```

You can see what query is actually generated by looking at the `query.Query.DebugQueryText` property.